# Event not firing in Ember-rails app

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to throw an alert up when enter key is hit after text entered in input. The warning at the bottom is what I'm getting - not able to find anything on google that works for me - anyone see where I've erred?

Cheers!

application.handlerbars

```
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="newEntryName" action="addEntry" }}
    {{newEntryName}}

</div>
```

Controller

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
     actions: ->
           addEntry: ->
               alert @newEntryName
```

In the console

**DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on controllers are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object (addEntry on )**

Comment: In the end I converted the coffee script to js and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valueBinding are deprecated instead must use value=newEntryName without quotes.
And your err is in actions delaration is not function is hash (js object) controller must look like this

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
 actions: 
       addEntry: ->
           alert @newEntryName
```

check this [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ELiNOsEk/1/)